# Set the position of QStatusBar in Python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm using a **QStatusBar** with couple of QLabels on it. It is positioned on the bottom center. Is it possible to move it a little to the right?

```
dlgMain = PyQt4.uic.loadUi("widgets/main.ui")
statusBar = QtGui.QMainWindow.statusBar(dlgMain)

label= QtGui.QLabel()
label.setStyleSheet("QFrame { color: Green }")
label.setText("%4.2f$" % statistics.profit)

statusBar.addWidget(label)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QStatusBar` is not quite meant to be moved around arbitrarily, although it's certainly doable. In a project of mine, I moved around a `QMenuBar`, which also is not an everyday task, but it worked out reasonably well *cough cough*.

But since you're still starting, you probably don't want to fight against the intricacies of Qt widget layouting when there's an easier way: Just use a plain `QWidget` with a `QHBoxLayout`. You can set this up in the Designer directly, and place it in your window as you desire.

Comment: Why is `self.Status_bar = QStatusBar(self) \n self.Status_bar.showMessage("Hi")` coming on top and `self.statusBar().showMessage("hi")` showing at bottom-left ( as expected)